# For what values of $x$ does $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}(x^n)$ exist?

Tags: real-analysis

For what values of $x$ does $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}(x^n)$ exist?
 Can this be solved by delta elipson definition? I think I have solved this in past but forgot how to solve it so can you show me how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Note that here there are two variables: $x$ and $n$

$$f(x)=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (x)^n = 1~\text{if}~ x=1, = 0 ~\text{if}~ 0 <x <1$$
For $x>1$, $f(x)$ becomes infinitly large so it does not exist.

$f(x)$ does not exist (it is non-real) if $x<0,$ because $-1=e^{i\pi}.$

Comment: bro I have another question there is a guy in comment section says for -1<x but you said if x<0 who is right who is wrong?

Comment: doesn't -1<x become null?

Comment: For  $-1<x<0$, $f(x)$  does not exist (it is nor real and finite). In fact this domain is included in $x<0$.in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that the limit must be finite, then $-1< x \leq 0$ and for such values it is $0$, if you work in the set of extended reals then the limit exists also for $x>1$ and its value is $+\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

In general for any complex number $z$ we can write $z=re^{i\theta}$ with $r\geq 0$ and $\theta$ real. Here $r$ is the magnitude of $z$, which dictates whether $z^n$ blows up to $\infty$, stays the same, or decreases to zero (since $|z^n|=r^n$). Namely when $r>1$ we have the infinite blowup, when $r<1$ it decreases to zero, and when $r=1$ the quantities $z^n$ oscillate around the unit circle of the complex plane.

Thus, we have convergence for all $z$ in the following set:
$$
\mathbb C\setminus \{e^{2\pi i\theta}\colon\theta\not\in \mathbb Z\},
$$
and the limit value depends only on $|z|$ as described above.

Answer (score 0):

Delta-epsilon proof:

**Convergence when $-1<x\leq 1$:**

The convergence when $x=1$ and $x=0$ is obvious. Let's assume $0<|x|<1$.

If $\epsilon \geq 1$, it is already true that $|x^n|< 1 \leq \epsilon$ for any $n$.

Let $0<\epsilon<1$. $|x^n|=|x|^n<\epsilon$ iff $n>\frac{\log\epsilon}{\log|x|}$ since $0<|x|<1$. That means we should choose $N_0$ to be the smallest integer larger than $\frac{\log\epsilon}{\log|x|}$ so that $|x^n-0|<\epsilon$ whenever $n>N_0$.

**Divergence when $x=-1$ or $|x|>1:$**

It is obvious that $(-1)^n$ is not convergent.

If $|x|>1$, notice that if $0<K<1$, it is already true that $|x^n|>K$ for all $n$.

If $K>1$, $|x^n|=|x|^n>K$ if we choose $n>\frac{\log K}{\log|x|}$.